# The Exif metadata of the jpeg 2000 images

Tags: java, image, exif

Is there any possibility to read the exif metadata of the jpeg 2000 images? I want specifically to read the width and the height from the exif metadata of jp2 images.

Moreover, I want to change this exif metadata when rewriting such images?

Comment: Read it as a binary file.

Comment: You could have a look at [this example](http://johnbokma.com/java/obtaining-image-metadata.html) as a starting point

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when it come to very big images, this code cannot execute. I would have this error 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dimensions (width=95168 height=154832) are too large

Comment: @didowa Did you try, or just assume that error? Normally, getting the metadata *does not* require reading or decoding the image data, only parsing the file headers which is a quite light-weight and fast task. You should not get this error.

Comment: I got the error, I have tried this and I got the error.
Yep, logically in order to read the metadata, there is no need to read the whole image. But I think the problem is once java discovers that the dimensions of this image is too big, it just stops and displays the dimensions are too large error..